# How to replace all fields in a table with value+rowID?

Tags: mysql, magento2

Trying to write a set of queries that replace specific table rows with a generated value of "sometext" + rowID.  So for example, I have a table called "customer_entity" and a row called "email", I'd like to walk through all records in this table, and replace email with "someone_"+ROWID+"@someplace.com". This allows me to keep the values unique, but also identifiable.

The part I'm not sure how to do, is to update all rows in x table while inserting the matched rowID for that row.

Debian9 (turnkeylinux)
MySQL 5.7 (Magento 2.2 table base)
uft8 - innodb

final results is to replace each email with a sanitized email address.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a ROWID this way:

```
SELECT @rowid:=0;
UPDATE `customer_entity` SET `email` = CONCAT('someone', @rowid:=@rowid+1, '@someplace.com');
```